# Photo and Video browser in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, photo-gallery

Is there any external library for **iOS** that supports *Photo browsing* as well as *video browsing* like the native photoAlbum in iPhone?

I know few libraries that supports photo browsing only, like: [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser), [EGOPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer), etc.

I'm looking for something like these but include video support as well.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

[PTShowcaseViewController](https://github.com/exalted/PTShowcaseViewController) support images, videos and PDFs.